# How to set a custom view's intrinsic content size in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, custom-controls, intrinsic-content-size

**Background**

I am making a vertical label to use with traditional Mongolian script. Before I was just rotating a `UILabel` but there were some performance issues and other complications with this. Now I am working on making a label from scratch. However, I need the vertical label to tell auto layout when its height adjusts (based on string length).

**What I have read**

I read the [Intrinsic Content Size](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AnatomyofaConstraint.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH9-SW21) and [Views with Intrinsic Content Size](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ViewswithIntrinsicContentSize.html) documentation. These were more about how to use it, though, and not how to define it in a custom view.

Searching for "ios intrinsic content size for a custom view" only gives me

- [Proper usage of intrinsicContentSize and sizeThatFits: on UIView Subclass with autolayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24127032/proper-usage-of-intrinsiccontentsize-and-sizethatfits-on-uiview-subclass-with-a)

in Stack Overflow. This particular question didn't even need intrinsic content size because their view was just an assembly of standard views.

**What I am trying**

What I am trying is my answer below. I am adding this Q&A pair so that it won't take other people as long to find the answer as it took me with the search keywords that I used.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Setting the intrinsic content size of a custom view lets auto layout know how big that view would like to be. In order to set it, you need to override `intrinsicContentSize`.

```
override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
   return CGSize(width: x, height: y)
}
```

Then call

```
invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
```

Whenever your custom view's intrinsic content size changes and the frame should be updated.

**Notes**

- **Swift 3 update**: [Easier Auto Layout: Coding Constraints in iOS 9](http://www.raywenderlich.com/125718/coding-auto-layout)
- Just because you have the intrinsic content size set up in your custom view doesn't mean it will work as you expect. Read [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AnatomyofaConstraint.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH9-SW21) for how to use it, paying special attention to [Content-Hugging and Compression-Resistance](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraintsinInterfaceBuidler.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH10-SW2).
- Thanks also to this Q&A for putting me on the right track: [How can I add padding to the intrinsic content size of UILabel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20874203/how-can-i-add-padding-to-the-intrinsic-content-size-of-uilabel)
- Thanks also to [this article](https://www.objc.io/issues/3-views/advanced-auto-layout-toolbox/) and the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/invalidateIntrinsicContentSize) for help with `invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()`.

Comment: For me adding @IBDesignable was needed to get Xcode to respect the content size.

Answer (score 17):

Example of a "view with intrinsic height" ...

```
@IBDesignable class HView: UIView {

    @IBInspectable var height: CGFloat = 100.0

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 99, height: height)
        // if using in, say, a vertical stack view, the width is ignored
    }

    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
         invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    }
}
```

[image]

which you can set as an inspectable

[image]

Since it has an intrinsic height, it can (for example) be immediately inserted in a stack view in code:

```
stack?.insertArrangedSubview(HView(), at: 3)
```

In contrast, if it was a normal view with no intrinsic height, you'd have to add a height anchor or it would crash:

```
let v:UIView = HView()
v.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
stack?.insertArrangedSubview(v, at: 3)
```

Note that in ...

## the important special case of a stack view:

- you set only ***ONE*** anchor (for vertical stack view, the height; for horizontal the width)

so, setting the intrinsic height works perfectly, since:

- the intrinsic height indeed means that the height anchor specifically will be set automatically if needed.

Remembering that in all normal cases of a subview, many other anchors are needed.

Comment: I'd recommend returning super.intrinsicContentSize.width for the width in the override rather than returning a constant like you suggest. This way when the view is used outside of a stack view and has a width constraint that constraint is respected.

Comment: hi @VojtaBöhm - sure thing, but the pedagogy here is to explain that, in fact, the width value is ignored when used in a layout case where the width value is ignored (stack view in the example)