# custom titleView of navigationItem is not getting tapped on iOS 11

Tags: ios, swift3, ios11

I am using a custom titleView and assigning it to navigationItem titleView. It had been working fine until iOS 11. Since the update it's position got misplaced to center as originally it was on more left. Beside that user interaction is not working.

```
titleView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("SomeNib", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? SomeNib
navigationItem.titleView = titleView
```

titleView is just a usual nib.

then for enabling interaction:

```
if let titleView = self.navigationItem.titleView {
            let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(onTitleViewTap))
            titleView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
            titleView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        }
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In iOS 11, titleView is getting set with Autolayout. Hence, the size of the titleView is the intrinsic size of the view you are setting in titleView.

This code in your view class(which you are setting as titleView) should help:

```
override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    return UILayoutFittingExpandedSize
}
```

Comment: where we need to call this `intrinsicContentSize`

Comment: On your "SomeNib" class

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36280699/how-to-set-a-custom-views-intrinsic-content-size-in-swift

Comment: well i have been looking for this concept. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

I have a created a Custom UIView with xib. Inside the UIView, I added `UILabel`, `ImageView` and a `UIButton` on top. On click on Hidden button I am able to call the click event.

[image]

import UIKit

```
    class NavBarTitleView: UIView {

        @IBOutlet weak var title : UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var clickButton: UIButton!
        
        /// Create an instance of the class from its .xib
        class func instanceFromNib() -> NavBarTitleView {
            return UINib(nibName: "NavBarTitleView", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! NavBarTitleView
        }
        
        //this line of code will help to enable a click event.
        override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
            return UIView.layoutFittingExpandedSize
        }
    }
```

Then in UIViewcontroler, I added the below code.

```
    if let title = self.navBarTitle{
        if navbarTitleView == nil {
            navbarTitleView = NavBarTitleView.instanceFromNib()
            self.navigationItem.titleView = navbarTitleView
        }
        navbarTitleView!.title.text = title
        navbarTitleView!.clickButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapNavbarTitle(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        navbarTitleView!.layoutIfNeeded()
        
    }else{
        navigationItem.title = ""
    }
```

Button action:

```
@objc func didTapNavbarTitle(_ sender: Any){
    print("NavBar Selected")
}
```

Result -
[image]

I hope this will work. Tested on code 11.6 and os version 13.6