# UIButton and Labels in Navigation Bar Title View in Storyboard

Tags: ios, uibutton, uinavigationbar, uistoryboard, uinavigationitem

I have added a couple labels and an image to my navigation title bar. That all works great. But I want to cover all of it with a `UIButton`, but I can't get the `UIButton` to register any taps.

Here's what my view hierarchy looks like:

[image: Nav Bar Views]

User interaction is enabled on everything, and I have an `IBAction` connected to the **Button** like this:

```
@IBAction func tapProjectEdit(_ sender: UIButton) {
  print("This never fires. :(")
}
```

Am I not allowed to have a `UIButton` in the navigation bar? Is there another way to pull this off?

Comment: Have you tried to add a UITapGestureRecognizer on titleView programmatically (instead of button) ?

Comment: That's a good idea. I just tried it and it still doesn't register any taps.

Comment: If I set the view like this: `self.navigationItem.titleView = buttonProjectEdit` the taps work (both the `IBAction` and the `UITapGestureRecognizer`), but then it removes my labels and only the button shows up.

Comment: Can you share the code how did you create TapGesture?

Comment: Here you go: https://d.pr/n/3BwMAJ

Comment: You added tap gesture to the button.

Comment: Remove that button at all , and add the gestureRecognizer to self.navigationItem.titleView. And do that in viewWillAppear method

Comment: Thanks for the idea, though I just tried that and it didn't work. I also tried creating an `IBOutlet` from **View** and then setting `self.navigationItem.titleView = view` and adding the gesture recognizer, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 5):

I finally figured this out. I had a suspicion that the `UIButton` (and everything else in the **View**) didn't have an actual size since navigation subviews always act a little funny.

So I subclassed `UIView`, set that class to the **View**, and added this:

```
class FancyTitleView: UIView{
  override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    return UILayoutFittingExpandedSize
  }
}
```

Now it's working with a regular `IBAction` (no gesture recognizer required).

This post helped me discover this: [custom titleView of navigationItem is not getting tapped on iOS 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46461350/custom-titleview-of-navigationitem-is-not-getting-tapped-on-ios-11)

Comment: Yes, it worked in my case too. `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46461350/custom-titleview-of-navigationitem-is-not-getting-tapped-on-ios-11/63241514#63241514`

Comment: Nice a clean! Thank you 