# How to subclass init#coder for a UITextView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uikit, ibdesignable

Say you have:

```
class TestField: UITextField {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        var f = frame
        f.size.height = 50.0
        super.init(frame: f)
    }
```

Of course when you `init` it (in code) it will force the height to be 50.

But say I want TestField to be actually loaded from storyboard:

```
class TestField: UITextField {
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        print("generally you can add some setup here")
    }
```

You can add some setup there to, example, change colors and so on.

But.

What I want is that the height of TestFields will be "50" (not the usual 25) when they are created.

Is there actually any way to do this?

As a bonus, it would be great if the height was even 50 (rather than 25) in storyboard (in an IBDesignable manner).

How to do?

Comment: Ah, you know what, what i was after was of course **intrinsicSize**...

Comment: ironically ! ........ https://stackoverflow.com/a/41650391/294884